# Is there .Net API for getting Display Name of AzureAD App Registration?

Tags: .net, adal, azure-ad-msal

I have .net daemon that is calling ASP.NET Web API using AzureAD authentication. My authentication flow follows this sample:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon

I would like to create a separate AD App registration for each daemon instance and identify instances in the Web API app by the Display name property of the App registration. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a REST API available for getting the application object data :

```
**https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{id}**
```

[image]

Permission for calling the above api require below set of permission:

[image]

BTW creating an application in Azure AD also post back the data with display name.

You can refer below docs for reference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-applications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#

Alternatively it is pretty easy if you are using powershell for getting the display name.

```
Get-AzureADApplication -Filter "AppId eq 'ed192e92-84d4-4baf-997d-1e190a81f28e'"
```

Reference :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadapplication?view=azureadps-2.0

Hope it helps.

Comment: Another option that we are considering is to use the management api
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.graph.rbac.fluent.iserviceprincipal?view=azure-dotnet

Management api might be needed anyway in our case, because we are considering adding an API method to the backend for rotating client secrets